# Comprehensive study of software complexity metrics

Tags: complexity-theory, metrics

Does anyone know of any work (academic or otherwise) that thoroughly compares the ability of software complexity metrics to predict the existence of bugs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like [crap4j](http://www.crap4j.org/) what you're looking for? I don't know that it predicts the existence of bugs, but it does help to highlight the most likely places for bugs to occur.

Comment: This is an interesting software package, but I was looking more for an analysis case study showing the predictive capabilities of each metric applied to some large code repository (eg. eclipse, chrome, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at "Empirical studies of quality models in object-oriented systems" by Briand and Wust. "[Predicting Maintainability with Object-Oriented Metrics - An Empirical Comparison](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=951372)" by Dagpinar and Jahnke, "[Object-oriented metrics that predict maintainability](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=170622)" by Li and Henry.